# two classes contain objects of each other

Tags: c++

i hope there's a simple answer to this.
without getting too complicated i have two classes. an "Animal" and a "Cell"
Cell contains an Animal as a member.
Animal has methods that accept Cells in their parameters.

i'm just confused as to how i #include each class the others header?
i've only ever had to go up a chain of classes and just included the last class header in the next and so on, but this circular situation has me a bit lost.

i hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use forward declarations to overcome the problem of circular references.

Example:

```
//animal.h

#include "cell.h"

class Animal {
public:
    void foo (Cell cell);
}

// cell.h

class Animal; // forward declaration

class Cell {
private:
    Animal * m_animal; // pointer to Animal object
}
```

Comment: brilliant!
thanks heaps, i figured there was a simple solution.
thanks again

Comment: @Julz: It's better to pass by reference, and question specified a different relationship for Animal within Cell…

Comment: yep, my bad. i'll be more specific next time.

Comment: if I want a member function in class `Cell` that its return type is `Animal` not `Animal*` , how should I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to forward declare one of the classes so that the compiler knows about it. Kind of like, there's this class "Animal", i'll tell you what it is later.

Example:

```
class Animal;

class Cell
{
    Animal *a;
};

class Animal
{
    Cell *c;
};
```

As Gareth notes in the comments, you may not forward declare something that will be passed by value. This is because the compiler can only deal with types that it knows the size of. A pointer to anything is always the same size, so the compiler does require Animal to be fully defined in the above example.

This will not work:

```
class Animal;

class Cell
{
    Animal a; // compiler needs to know how Animal is defined
}             // and so will fail at this point
```

Comment: -1: forward declaration does not allow you to define a member by value, only by pointer or reference.  So, in your example above - after forward-declaring `class Animal`, `Cell` could have an `Animal* a` member, but not `Animal a`.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic dependencies are handled with [forward declarations](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/HeaderFileIncludePatterns.htm) (scroll to the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

If `Cell` contains `Animal` as a member then a full definition of `Animal` is needed before `Cell` is defined so you would need to `#include` the header that defines `Animal` from the header that defines `Cell`.

```
#include "animal.h"

class Cell
{
    // ...
    Animal animal; // animal member
};
```

If `Animal` has methods that take or return a `Cell` (whether by reference or value) then you can just forward declare `Cell` before the definition of `Animal` like this.

```
// animal.h
class Cell;

class Animal
{
    // declarations of Animal methods
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for two classes each to contain objects of the other's type - one or both of the classes will have to contain a pointer to the other's type.

Answer (score 1):

animal.h:

```
class Cell; // fwd declaration

// Cell is now an "incomplete type"

class Animal {
    void Respirate( Cell & ); // reference: no need for complete type
};
```

cell.h:

```
#include "animal.h"

class Cell {
    Animal organism; // conceptually, a reference or pointer would be better
};
```

OR

```
class Animal

class Cell {
    Animal *organism; // Cell "knows about an" animal rather than "has an"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can forward declare, but this doesn't completely solve the problem, it only lets you declare a pointer to that object, not use any functions/members inside that object.  You can do this:

Animal.h

```
class Cell;

class Animal {
  private:
  Cell cell;
};
```

Animal.cpp

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Cell.h"

// Animal functions can use members/functions in Cell object here
```

Cell.h

```
class Animal;

class Cell
{
  private:
    Animal animal;
};
```

Cell.cpp

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Cell.h"

// Cell functions can use members/functions in Animal object here
```

This way both objects are able to completely use the features of the other (except in the headers, but that's fine)